# Generalizing a string to int conversion technique in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string-parsing, base-n

I'm looking for a faster alternative of `parseInt()`

---

I recently found out this technique of converting a base 10 numeric string into an int in JavaScript:

```
var x = "1234567890" - 0 ;
```

Of course, this is restricted to base 10. I would like to know if there is any way of generalizing this to any base while preserving the efficiency. Thanks.

Somewhat relevant, but not directly related to the question:
I ran a little test to compare its performance with the built-in `parseInt()` function. The -0 method is 15~16 times faster.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the benchmarking code I'm using, and the console output is bellow it. Apparently, "1234"+0 is the fastest one.

```
var n = 1000000 ;
var x;

//parseInt with radix 10
t0 = Date.now(); console.log(t0);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x = parseInt("1234567890", 10) ;
}
t1 = Date.now(); console.log(t1);

console.log(t1-t0);


//parseInt without specifying the radix
t0 = Date.now(); console.log(t0);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x = parseInt("1234567890") ;
}
t1 = Date.now(); console.log(t1);

console.log(t1-t0);


//using - 0 to convert string to int
t0 = Date.now(); console.log(t0);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x = "1234567890" - 0 ;
}
t1 = Date.now(); console.log(t1);

console.log(t1-t0);

//using =+ to convert string to int
t0 = Date.now(); console.log(t0);
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    x = +"1234567890" ;
}
t1 = Date.now(); console.log(t1);

console.log(t1-t0);
```

Console:

```
[01:58:05.559] 1393225085558
[01:58:05.623] 1393225085622
[01:58:05.623] 64
[01:58:05.623] 1393225085623
[01:58:05.683] 1393225085683
[01:58:05.684] 60
[01:58:05.684] 1393225085684
[01:58:05.689] 1393225085689
[01:58:05.689] 5
[01:58:05.689] 1393225085689
[01:58:05.786] 1393225085786
[01:58:05.786] 97
```

Comment: `var x = +"1234567890";` is easier imho.

Comment: nice, can't wait to benchmark this. thanks @Jack

Comment: "Of course, this is restricted to base 10". Not sure if this is true. I tried "0xF"-0 and it returned 15

Comment: @SajithNair The hexadecimal case is the only one that does that iirc

Comment: How do you expect to have a "general solution to any base" that doesn't use `parseInt()` where you pass the base?  Confused as to what you could possibly be looking for?

Comment: looking for a faster alternative of `parseInt()`. I did not say I don't want to pass the base. @jfriend00

Comment: Well `parseInt()` is a generalized solution.  If what you want is something faster than `parseInt()`, then please edit your question to explain that that is exactly what you want.  Your question is simply not clear.  Yes, you say that `parseInt()` isn't fast, but you don't say that performance is the issue you want to fix.  You can see by Jack's answer that it must not be clear what you want.

Comment: I edited before responding to your comment :)

Comment: I'd suggest you edit the title of your question too.

Comment: What would you suggest changing the title to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a generic solution, you will want to use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var x = parseInt("1234567890"); // automatic base detection

var x = parseInt("777", 8); // force octal base (511)
```

Note that although the radix argument is optional, it's a good practice to always include it, i.e.:

```
parseInt("09"); // may fail
parseInt("09", 10); // always 9
```

If you're only looking for base-10 and base-16 conversions:

```
+"1234" // 1234
+"0xf" // 15
```

Comment: While [*parseInt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) is supposed to default to base 10 in ES5, most implementations still use ES ed 3 in this regard and `parseInt('09')` gives `0`, so always include a radix: `parseInt('09', 10)`.

Comment: @Jack, I'm actually looking for a faster (if possible) alternative of the `parseInt()`. See the the last two lines of my post, I mentiond `parseInt()`.

Comment: @Raiyan Decimal or hexadecimal are the only flavours that go faster :)

Comment: @Jack, I agree (until proven wrong) dec and hex are the only ones where this kind of type coercion works. But not sure if +"1234" is actually faster than "1234"+0. Please see the benchmarking code and console output I posted (EDIT).

Comment: @Raiyan I suggest you use [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) for benchmarks, don't make your own.